# Trying to work with an enum that has duplicate values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, enums

I have an enum of type String which needs to have multiple variables that have the same value.  My enum looks something like this:

```
class MyClass {

  enum MyEnum: String {
    case blahA = "blaha"
    case blahB = "blahb"
    ...
    static var blahD = "blah"
    static var blahE = "blah"
  }
}
```

The reason why I'm using static var's in the above construction is because both "blahD" and "blahE" need to reference the same String value, used in different places (don't ask me why, it just has to be this way).  However, I have a method where I need to pass in the value of the enum as follows:

```
if let testString = myString(foo: MyEnum.blahD) {...}
```

I unfortunately am getting the following compilation error:

> Cannot convert value of type "String" to expected argument type "MyClass.MyEnum".

How do I get around passing the above variable which has duplicate values in my enum in the method, but cast it to the type of "MyClass.MyEnum"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if you make the extra case reference the other enum case directly instead of just assigning them the same string value:

```
class MyClass {

  enum MyEnum: String {
    case blahA = "blaha"
    case blahB = "blahb"
    ...
    case blahD = "blah"
    static var blahE = MyEnum.blahD
  }
}
```

Then you can pass `MyEnum.blahE` the same way you would pass `MyEnum.blahD`

Answer (score 1):

If the function takes a value of type `MyEnum`, you cannot do this. The type properties `blahD` and `blahE` are simply not of that type. Only the `case`s of the enum are of type `MyEnum`.

The function parameter's type must be changed to `String`.

The only other way around it would be to add a case to the enum that has a raw value matching the value of those two properties: `case blahDOrE = "blah"`.  Then you could construct that case: `MyEnum(rawValue: MyEnum.blahD)`, but I can't see that being very useful.